# Is echo response data in register_rest_route callback acceptable?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I'd like to know if my approach here is acceptable in WordPress API routing. I need pretty JSON returned from [register_rest_route](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) callback. I can only accomplish this doing an **echo** response body in callback instead of **return** response body. API says **return bool** True on success, false on error, but most examples show **return** response body.

> [image]

```
register_rest_route( 
    'example/v1', 
    '/test/(?P<id>[\d]+)', 
    array(
        'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'get_info',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true'             
    ));
}
```

callback...

```
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    echo $error_message;
    return false;
} else {       
  $body = rest_ensure_response( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ));
  echo json_encode(json_decode($body->data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  return true; 
}
```

results...

```
// this is no good. return gives me nasty json.
// "[\n {\n \"example_a\": \"a\",\n \"example_b\": \"b\",\n \"example_c\": \"c\" }\n]"
// return json_encode(json_decode($body->data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

// this is what I want. echo works perfectly.   
[
    {
        "example_a": "a"
        "example_b": "b"
        "example_c": "c"
    }
]
```

Comment: "Pretty" means that line breaks will appear and that "nasty" JSON is valid, only its with escape sequences.

Comment: Yes. The answer I’m looking for is whether “echo” vs “return” is Ok.